# Automation Script using Selenium webdriver

Tags: for-loop, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am getting element not visible every time when I run my script. Can you please help me what exactly am I doing wrong? I am trying but not getting a proper solution. I am new to Selenium. This is my code:

```
public void Click_Smart_Cart_Button() throws IOException, FilloException, InterruptedException
{

  System.out.println(".....Click operation on Add_Smart_Cart_Device button......");
  WebElement w1=driver.findElement(By.xpath(rx.readdatafromexcel("sheet1", 1,1))); 
  for(int i=0;i<=1;i++)
  {
  mod.click(w1);
  System.out.println("    ");
  System.out.println("....Button is clicked Successfully....");
  System.out.println("    ");
```

// Operation to Retrieve data from the Excel Sheet "TestData"

```
  Fillo fillo= new Fillo();
  Connection con=fillo.getConnection(Filepath);
  String query = "Select SmartCartDeviceID, SmartCartDeviceName from Sheet1";//the parameters name and column name in excel sheet must be same.Eg "username"
  Recordset results= con.executeQuery(query); 

  while(results.next()){
```

//Click on Device id text box and send data from sheet

```
 System.out.println("....Click operation on Smart Card Device id text box....... ");
 System.out.println("    ");
 WebElement w2=driver.findElement(By.xpath(rx.readdatafromexcel("sheet1", 2,1)));
 mod.click(w2);
 System.out.println("......Smart card device id box is clicked Sucessfully.....");
 System.out.println("   ");
 System.out.println("....Checking whther the id box field is empty or not...");
 System.out.println("  ");

  if(w2 != null)
  {
      w2.clear();
  }
 w2.sendKeys(results.getField("SmartCartDeviceID"));
 Thread.sleep(2000);
 System.out.print("Device id is "+results.getField("SmartCartDeviceID") +" ");
 System.out.println("    ");
 System.out.println("......Device id is sent succefully from the excel sheet.....");
 System.out.println("  ");
```

//Click on Device name text box and send data from the sheet

```
 System.out.println(".....Click operation on Smart Card Device Name Text Box...");
 System.out.println("   ");
 WebElement w4=driver.findElement(By.xpath(rx.readdatafromexcel("sheet1", 3,1)));
 mod.click(w4); 
 System.out.println("......Smart Cart Device id box is clicked Successfully....");
 System.out.println("  ");
 System.out.println("....Checking whther the Device name box field is empty or not.....");
 System.out.println(" ");

 if(w4  !=null)
  {
      w4.clear();
  }
  w4.sendKeys(results.getField("SmartCartDeviceName"));
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  System.out.println(" Device Name is "+results.getField("SmartCartDeviceName"));
  System.out.println("  ");
  System.out.println("....Device name is sent successfully from the excel sheet.....");
  System.out.println("   ");
```

//Click on Save button after sending values to the respective text boxes

```
  System.out.println("...Click on Save button....");
  WebElement w5=driver.findElement(By.xpath(rx.readdatafromexcel("sheet1",4,1)));
  mod.click(w5);
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  System.out.println("   ");
  System.out.println("......Save button is clicked successfully.....");
```

//Handle Confirmation Pop up

```
  System.out.println("  ");  
  System.out.println(".....After click on save confimation window will appear....");
  System.out.println(" ");
  WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(rx.readdatafromexcel("sheet1",5,1))));
  System.out.println("....Wait for element to be clickable.....");
  WebElement w6=driver.findElement(By.xpath(rx.readdatafromexcel("sheet1", 5,1)));
  mod.click(w6);
  Thread.sleep(5000);
  System.out.println("  ");
  System.out.println("....Successfully clicked on confirmation ok.....");
  System.out.println("  ");
  System.out.println(".....Successfully completed data retrievation from excel sheet.....");
  System.out.println(" ");
}
```

Comment: Well, is the element really visible? Can you please post the relevant error log?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response.This is the error what i got org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

Comment: See, if you post more of the error, it will be easier for us to help you. So far I know that you are getting the 'element not visible' exception, but I cannot tell if it is really not visible (you can tell me, supposedly). I don't even know which is the element in question.

Comment: What is the value of `rx.readdatafromexcel("sheet1", 2,1)`?

Comment: Thank you...i rectify the error and i got the solution.Actually i did not make the button visible.So i put explicit wait condition and its works fine.About your question that value is nothing but my xpath for that particular element.I create a framework and try to retrieve my data from excel sheet.

Comment: But i am facing one more problem.I want to verify whether my excel sheet data is added to the list or not.For that i am not getting proper solution for how to verify my excel data with table?Can you please help me?

Comment: It would be the best if you asked a new question, this time with your code and the error you are getting, e.g. what do you mean when you say data is not added to the list.